# Why the FF:FE in EUI-64?

Tags: ipv6, mac-address, ip-address

EUI-64 IPv6 addresses are generated from MAC addresses by taking the network prefix (64 bits) and appending the first half of the MAC address, then `FF:FE`, then the second half of the MAC. Is there a reason for the `FF:FE`? Other than 64+64=128.

Note: I didn't mention in the above that some bits in the prefix, specifically the "global" identifier and the "unique" identifier, get flipped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0xFFFE was chosen by the IEEE as a reserved value to reflect the fact that a given address is in the *modified* EUI-64 format.

It's important to note that the first and second half of a MAC address actually have significance - the first being the organizationally unique identifier (OUI) that identifies the NIC manufacturer/class and the second being a number assigned by said manufacturer.

So - we have [8-byte prefix]+[3-byte OUI]+[FF-FE, 2 bytes]+[3-byte assigned NIC value] = 16 bytes, 128 bits.

[Here](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/100566/understanding-ipv6-eui-64-bit-address) is a good reference explaining the above.

Comment: Don't forget to flip the U/L bit.